# Rails allow to access only two pages after registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a situation where User after successfully Sign up process (I'm using Devise gem) will have access only for two controllers until he passes all validation process. To check if validation process is in progress I'm using `status` column. If `status == ''` means validation is not finished.

I'm wondering how to implement such an access to only two pages? my first thought was Pundit gem but if I have 50 controllers I would need to implement 50 policies, inside of which I'll have numerous methods correspondent to controller actions. Is there any better way to do so?

[EDIT]

This is what I have so far:

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorized_user
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def authorized_user
    policy_scope(current_user)
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

User policy:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      return raise(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError) unless user.status == 'active'

      scope.all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tip: In Rails that often translates to `record.status?` which tests not only for `nil`, but also empty strings and strings entirely composed of whitespace characters.

Comment: You can use tools like Pundit to make your ACL (Access Control List) policies. You can make as few or as many policies as you want. Maybe make a policy for "validated" and then apply that more broadly? One trick is to inherit all your "requires validation" controllers from an intermediate controller class that does the validation check.

Comment: @tadman But this "intermediate controller class" should have some kind of `before_action` ? What would a policy that accepts all methods from these controllers look like?

Comment: Yeah, that's usually how it plays out. It depends on what Pundit wants you to do.

Comment: @tadman could you please take a look what I have right now? Is this how it should be or did I missed something?

Comment: Yeah, I think you've got the right idea there. You may need to test and refine that a bit, but that's what I'd expect to see.

Comment: Could you please post reply with this code? I will mark it for future generations ;)

Comment: You produced the code, so I'd suggest adding it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions in the comments from @tadam I ended up with below code:

```
#intermediate controller class
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorized_user
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def authorized_user
    authorize :global, :only_active?
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Global policy used in BaseController

```
class GlobalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def only_active?
    active?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This Answer only works if your controllers inherit from ApplicationController.

Add a `before_action` to your ApplicationController which does something when the user is not validated. This triggers now on all controller actions.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_validated

  private

  def require_validated
    redirect_to somewhere_url unless current_user.status == 'validated'
  end
end
```

To except specific controller you can `skip_before_action`

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_validated
  # skip only for specific actions
  skip_before_action :require_validated, only: [:new, :create]
end
```