# Rails pundit user scope Minitest won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

In my app User only with `status == 'active'` has access to all application pages. I've create a scope policy for that action and a separate intermediate controller in which I set all global policies. As follows:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      return raise(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError) unless user.status == 'active'

      scope.all
    end
  end
end

class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorized_user
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def authorized_user
    policy_scope(current_user)
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

Now I want to have a MiniTest for this scope policy. This is what I've got:

require 'test_helper'

```
class UserPolicyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context 'when user is active' do
    def setup
      @user = user(:active)
      @properties = properties(:one)
    end

    def scope_test
      # user should have access to the show page in properties controller
      refute_equal properties, user
      assert permit(user, properties, :show)
    end
  end
end
```

What did I missed? when I run this it shows me:

```
Finished in 0.185689s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: You really shoud use `authorize(User)` or whatever the class is instead of raising Pundit::NotAuthorizedError from inside the scope. That will call `index?` on the policy. Its not the job of a scope to controll overall access.

Comment: I don't get it, works pretty well

Comment: It may work - but its a horrible practice. And it will blow up in your face as the complexity of your app increases.

Comment: How come? What would you suggest instead? I don't want to authorize user inside each controller, it don't make sense to me if I can do the same via intermediate controller class from which other controllers can inherits.

Comment: Because scopes don't know the context - eg. which method is called. Its also a really suprising and unexpected behavior to anyone used to pundit.

Comment: I don't know if it's suprising and unexpected behaviour, I based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101478/rails-allow-to-access-only-two-pages-after-registration?noredirect=1#comment118608161_67101478

Comment: You're referencing an answer you wrote yourself? Whatever floats your boat then. Lets just agree to disagree.

Comment: I refer to the comment which I linked.

Comment: I don't see how @tadmans comment is in any way is connected to scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it all pretty backwards. Its not the job of a scope to control overall access.

```
class ApplicationPolicy

  class Scope
    def resolve
      @user.active?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.none
      end
    end
  end

  # ...

  def show?
    @user.active?
  end 

  def index?
    @user.active?
  end


  private

  def active?
    user.active? # user.status == 'active' is iffy. Don't let the logic leak outside of the object
  end
end
```

If you want to authorize the the actions of a controller you would do:

```
def show
  authorize(Thing.find(params[:id]))
end

def index
  authorize(Thing) # controlls overall access - often skipped
  @things = policy_scope(Thing)
end
```

If you really want to add a scope to the show method you would do:

```
def show
  authorize(policy_scope(Thing).find(params[:id]))
end
```

The reason your scope should NOT be controlling overall access is that is does not know the context (which action is called). So while this may "work" right now its going to blow up in your face when stuff gets more complicated.

If you then want to test a specific policy you would do:

```
assert ThingPolicy.new(thing, user).show?
```

If you want to test a scope you resolve the scope and test that the expected records are included/not included.

Comment: But what in case when I have 50 controllers and inactive users should have access only for 2 of them while all other actions inside of the other controllers should be unavailable to it? In your approach I should put policy inside of all 50 controllers which is not worthwhile in my opinion.

Comment: No - you're looking at the problem completely wrong. Use callbacks in your controller to load and authorize resources. By using inheritance or modules you can DRY your code to cut duplication. If you don't want to specify policies for each of you controllers you can quite simply just tell pundit explicitly which policy you want to use.

Comment: If you want to cut duplication between policies again use inheritance or modules.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - I should use the scope you wrote (placed directly in the ApplicationPolicy) and then in each controller that requires this validation use `before_action` with authorize(name_of_model/controller/whatever is inside) ? how would that work?

Comment: No - If you just do `before_action :my_method_name` in your BaseController every subclass will then inherit this callback. Subclasses can change the logic by skipping the callback or implementing `my_method_name`.

Comment: You could do a global headless policy by `def my_method_name; authorize :global, :anything?; end`. And it would call `GlobalPolicy#anything?` but quite honestly if thats all you want why even use pundit?

Comment: Hm... so I don't need this scope at all. I could just do `before_action :authorized_user` where authorized_user method is: `authorize(current_user)`. Then define `@user.active?` inside of ApplicationPolicy for each action. That make sense! but why does the pundit documentation show this sentence: `Often, you will want to have some kind of view listing records which a particular user has access to. When using Pundit, you are expected to define a class called a policy scope.`

Comment: A policy scope is used to fetch records that the user should have access to. For example in a PostPolicy::Scope you would check if the user is an editor and use that to restict who can see draft posts on the index page.

Comment: The second sentance should really be read more like "In Pundit this is implemented by creating a policy scope."